# Quiero que una animación se quite a los 5 segundos, es para hacer un preloader. Utilice HTML y CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #121212;
    color: white;
    min-height: 100vh;
}
body, .cubo, .loading {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.container {
    width: 20%;
    height: 300px;
}
.cubo {
    height: 60%;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    animation: rotar 8s linear infinite}
.cubo > span {
    position: absolute;
    width: 4em;
    height: 4em;
    border: 2px solid white;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 15px 5px rgba(67, 195, 255, .2), 0px
    0px 40px 1px rgba(67, 195, 255, .15);
    border-radius: 4px;
} 
.cubo > span:nth-child(1){transform: rotateY(90deg)translateZ(2em);
}
.cubo > span:nth-child(2){transform: rotateY(90deg)translateZ(-2em);
}
.cubo > span:nth-child(3){transform: rotateY(90deg)translateZ(-2em);
}
.cubo > span:nth-child(4){transform: rotateY(90deg)translateZ(2em);
}
.cubo > span:nth-child(5){transform: translateZ(-2em);}
.cubo > span:nth-child(6){transform: translateZ(2em);}
.loading{
    height: 40%;
}

@keyframes rotar {
    0%{transform: rotateY(0deg)rotateX(0deg);}
    50%{transform: rotateY(360deg)rotateX(360deg);}
    100%{transform: rotateY(0deg)rotateX(0deg);}
}

h1, p {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: 100;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>loader</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
      <div class="cubo">
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
      </div>
      <div class="Loading">
       <div>
           <h1>Loading</h1>
           <p>...</p>
       </div>   
      </div>
  </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Quiero que la animación se quite la animación a los 5 segundos. No sé Javascript. Lo agradecere mucho si me ayudan. Aún no he añadido más texto, aún es una prueba, pero después ya añadire texto.

Comment: tu copias esto que pones de algunn sitio donde ponen varios loaders para elegir y luego vienes aqui para que te hagamos la parte del js, pues no funcionan asi las cosas, tu tienes que demostrar que lo has intentado...

Comment: No lo sé @HernánGarcia, ha hecho un poco de investigación o búsqueda, al punto que ya sea por copy+paste tiene una animación, y como bien dice, necesita una ayudita con JS que no domina. De acuerdo contigo, totalmente, cuando lo que quieren es que hagamos tareas de la escuela o la U,

Comment: Igual no me voy a arriesgar, conozco bien las limitaciones que ponen las reglas del SO.  Dejaré mi fiddle por acá, eso es todo:  https://jsfiddle.net/0tw2u1or/

Comment: @DEVX75, no me gusta mucho el " si me pasan el código hecho, mucho mejor"...

Comment: @HernánGarcia, ante todo ha sido honesto al decir que no sabe JS, hay que sugerirle cortesmente que lea las reglas de este foro.. Sobre todo, cómo preguntar.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: [es.so] no es un servicio de código. Debes mostrar lo que has intentado: "no sé cómo hacerlo" no es motivo suficiente como para publicarlo aquí. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Me funaron xd, la verdad, sí, lo he copiado, pero lo he copiado de un vídeo, el cual solo ten-ía ese código, no venía el JS, he tenido que copiar el código del vídeo, no le di Ctrl+v. Además solo he pedido ayuda con la parte del js. Y no recuerdo haber escrito "si me pasan el código mucho mejor". Se me cuidan.

Comment: Gracias a los que me ayudaron. La verdad no buscaba que me funaran, perdón si los he hecho perder su tiempo. Adiós.

Comment: No es _funar_. Es por eso que se te indicó que hagas el [tour] :) En el [centro de ayuda](/help) podés ver qué preguntar y qué no. Además, por salud del sitio, buscamos lo más posible que las preguntas y respuestas sean de calidad, y que cuenten con respuestas _aceptadas_ (ya que caso contrario vuelven a aparecer una y otra vez en la página principal). Por sobre todo, tené en cuenta que [es.so] no es un foro de discusión: es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas _específicas_.

Comment: A bueno xd, pero igual gracias.

Answer (score 0):

esto te puede funcionar (usar un setTimeOut para ocultar el div 'container' despues de 5 segundos)

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  setTimeout(function () {
    document.querySelector(".container").style.display = "none";
    document.querySelector(".containerReal").style.display = "block";
  }, 5000);
});
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #121212;
    color: white;
    min-height: 100vh;
}
body, .cubo, .loading {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.container {
    width: 20%;
    height: 300px;
}
.cubo {
    height: 60%;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    animation: rotar 8s linear infinite}
.cubo > span {
    position: absolute;
    width: 4em;
    height: 4em;
    border: 2px solid white;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 15px 5px rgba(67, 195, 255, .2), 0px
    0px 40px 1px rgba(67, 195, 255, .15);
    border-radius: 4px;
} 
.cubo > span:nth-child(1){transform: rotateY(90deg)translateZ(2em);
}
.cubo > span:nth-child(2){transform: rotateY(90deg)translateZ(-2em);
}
.cubo > span:nth-child(3){transform: rotateY(90deg)translateZ(-2em);
}
.cubo > span:nth-child(4){transform: rotateY(90deg)translateZ(2em);
}
.cubo > span:nth-child(5){transform: translateZ(-2em);}
.cubo > span:nth-child(6){transform: translateZ(2em);}
.loading{
    height: 40%;
}

@keyframes rotar {
    0%{transform: rotateY(0deg)rotateX(0deg);}
    50%{transform: rotateY(360deg)rotateX(360deg);}
    100%{transform: rotateY(0deg)rotateX(0deg);}
}

h1, p {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: 100;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-size: 18px;
}
.containerReal {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>loader</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="containerReal">
      <h1>Hola mundo</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="cubo">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      </div>
      <div class="Loading">
        <div>
          <h1>Loading</h1>
          <p>...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```